# Send context from bot - Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework, bots

I am developing Bots using Microsoft Bot framework and I've a use-case where my bot have to send a custom context information to my application. I am thinking to use ChannelData like below. 
Is this a correct placeholder?

```
      Dictionary<string, string> context = new Dictionary<string, string>{
      { "foo","bar" }};

      Dictionary<string, object> channelinfo = new Dictionary<string, object>
      {{ "context", context }};

      ResponseActivity.ChannelData = channelinfo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom channel data to outgoing activities by creating a custom store middleware to modify activities sent by the user. Channel data is a channel-specific property bag that can be used to send non-standard in-band data.To implement channel-specific functionality, you can pass metadata to a channel in the activity object's channel data property. Take a look at the  **[Backchannel Piggyback on Outgoing Activities](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities)** Web Chat Sample in which all the 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY' sent on the bot will have an email added to the channel data.

Depending on the channel you are using, you can make use of the channel data property to instruct your channel to implement the functionality. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation provides a detailed explanation on how to create a custom messsage for different channels.

A simple example of the channel data for a message via Facebook Messenger in NodeJS and C# is explained in detail in this [blogpost](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/03/28/custom-channel-data/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I explored middleware method which looks suitable for my requirement. but how about using custom adapters ?

Comment: For your requirement, I think a middleware would be more suitable, as with a custom adapter you will not be able to send any type of data you want to and still need to make use of channelData to follow the channel schema.

Comment: Can you please brief me about the type of data that you are talking about ?

Comment: In your case, it is the custom context information. If you are using the email channel, then it would contain the email’s body, subject, and recipients or attachments. What I specifically mean by the type of data is "internal data within the message that is specific to each channel"